# In ASP.NET Core, why AddOpenIdConnect does not have AuthorizationEndpoint as an option, like AddoAuth has?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

OIDC required Authorization endpoint. Nevertheless, AddOpenIDConnect does not have AuthorizationEndpoint option, which AddOAuth has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenID Connect handler usually uses a special "discovery" endpoint to find the authorization endpoint (among other things).
It takes your Authority and appends "/.well-known/openid-configuration" to it to get the metadata.

From there it gets the `authorization_endpoint` from the JSON.

For example, setting the authority to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0` (Azure AD) will fetch the metadata from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration.

```json
{
  "authorization_endpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
}
```

Note this is what the handler does by default with minimal configuration.
You can set `MetadataAddress` instead of `Authority` to set the discovery endpoint URL manually.
If you do not wish to use the discovery endpoint at all,
you can provide the `Configuration` property manually:

```cs
o.Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration
{
    // Other properties omitted
    AuthorizationEndpoint = ""
};
```